# How can I set my x higher? I need it to be at least 1000e8, but the I get a overflow error

Tags: python, plot, overflow, derivative

How do I prevent the Overflow Error? It only happens once I set my x higher than 400e4 I need it to go at least to 1000e5
I need the derivative of the function f and after that I would like to plot it for different gamma. It works fine, when I set my x low enough. How do I get rid of the overflow though?
The results I am Expecting are in the range of e-8 - e-9, I only need numbers with about 20 digits

```
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



x, k_1, k_2, k_3, T_0, T_S, T, f_p, gamma = smp.symbols('x k_1 k_2 k_3 T_0 T_S T f_p gamma', real=True) 
aT = 10**((8.86*(T_0 - T_S)/(101.6 + (T_0 - T_S))-(8.86*(T-T_S-f_p*x)/(101.6+(T-T_S)))))
f = smp.log((k_1 * aT) / ((1 + gamma * k_2 * aT) ** k_3)) 

dfdx = smp.diff(f, x) 
dfdx_f = smp.lambdify((gamma, x, k_1, k_2, k_3, T_0, T_S, T, f_p), dfdx)   
gamma = np.linspace(0, 10000, 1000) 

y = (dfdx_f(gamma,  x=400e5, k_1=1000, k_2=0.01, k_3=0.94, T_0=243.9243, T_S=178.73, T=250.0, f_p=0.001001412))
plt.plot(gamma, y)
```

Comment: Which line gives you the overflow?

Comment: y = (dfdx_f(gamma,  x=400e5, k_1=1000, k_2=0.01, k_3=0.94, T_0=243.9243, T_S=178.73, T=250.0, f_p=0.001001412))
If I change the value of x in this line, I get an overflow